# PicTeX files inside a Plain TeX file

Tags: diagrams, plain-tex

I am using Plain TeX to write my (scientific) texts which usually include many awful equations and graphs (or figures) I am constructing with unsurpassed PicTeX. My big problem is that with my MikTeX version I cannot input more than two `\input pictex` in one Plain TeX file (at the third pictex call the file cannot be texified and blows out). So I have to write a separate file for each extra graph above two, to output their pdf file, and to merge at the end all the pdf with the defect that the extra figure files are at the end of the text (and not in the body of the text as for usual texbooks).

Is there a way to set TeX parameters so that more than two pictex calls can be made in one Plain TeX file? Thanks for solution (If you insist that I have to run LaTeX, I am not really a big fan because LaTeX is relatively limited).

Comment: Did you already tried the `m-pictex` and `pictexwd` packages to increase the number of `dimen` registers?

Comment: Are you using TeX82 or pdfTeX? The latter has more registers available, so you'd only need to make TeX use them by altering the allocation routine (as is done by `etx.sty` for LaTeX but is also quite doable for plain TeX).

Comment: (Just to add that you can use pdfTeX as the engine while still getting DVI output. That's no always clear to people not familiar with pdfTeX.)

Comment: Could we see a snippet of your PicTeX as an example? I couldn't figure out how to use its macros.

Comment: No reply from unregistered user to comments requesting more information: without this the question cannot be answers.